# Couldn't make State Variable Filter Work

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

Me and my friend tried to set a state variable filter to get bandpass output. But neither of us could have achieve it. We both set the exact circuit as in the figure for 10 times in total. We observed low pass rather than bandpass at the relevant output and decrease in the amplitude rather than increase. What might be the problem? We intended to get q=30 and center freq 1k hz.

Note that, we have used lm358 op-amps with +/- 12 Vcc values. R1=R2=R5=R6=10kohm, R7=560k, R3=R4=16kohm, C1=C2=10nF.

[image: State Variable Filter]

Comment: Why do you expect this circuit to be a band-pass filter?

Comment: I have researched about this circuit and made analysis in s domain. Bandpass output is really bandpass output in theoretical. So we decided to set this up as part of a project.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly throwing the circuit into LTSpice shows that it is indeed a lowpass with a large amount of peaking.
EDIT: As Andy aka pointed out, I made a silly mistake.

The circuit has three nodes. The first opamp's output has a high-pass characteristic. The second opamp's output hasa bandpass characteristic. The final node has a low-pass charactersitic. Perhaps you and your friend (just like me the first time) probed the output of the third opamp, and thus measured the low-pass node?

Here is a comparison in LTspice, this time without quite so quick throwing:

[image]

Comment: Why have you got a 1 ohm on the output of the right most op-amp to ground and where is vn002 on your circuit?

Comment: Vn002 is the output of the last opamp. I have the 1ohm there due to me being used to doing that (to avoid no-load wierdness. Since it's ac analysis the value doesn't really matter, 1ohm is nice because it makes current eaqual to voltage).

Comment: That's the low pass output. The op is asking about the band pass output. Maybe you and he have made the same mistake?

Comment: It would appear that in my haste I have. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It was the quick throwing that did it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let's hope the it's of some help to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for having time on my question. Maybe you're right but probably we have used the right output,namely, output of the second op-amp. However, we will try it again, because it provides most of the parameters as you want. May our error be related with the opamp model? I have also analysed circuit in Multisim with lm358 before setting up on breadboard, everything was fine. But in the lab, we failed unexpectedly.